# progressbar is not showing in all device...(5 or heigher)

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar, android-progressbar

**ProgressBar**

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarMain"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        />
```

**Allotment.java**

```
public class Allotment extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webViewCir;
    ProgressBar bar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_allotment);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        final WebView webViewCir = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewAllot);
        webViewCir.setWebViewClient(new mywebclint());
        webViewCir.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webViewCir.loadUrl("http://www.rwdbihar.in/article_allotments_d.aspx?config_id=8");

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                webViewCir.loadUrl("http://www.rwdbihar.in/article_allotments_d.aspx?config_id=8");
            }});

        bar=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarAllot);



    }



    public class mywebclint extends WebViewClient{
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }
        enter code here
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);`enter code here`
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have a webView which is placed all over activity and a progress bar.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this below code..**

```
   private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressDialog_webview = new ProgressDialog(Yourclassname.this);
                progressDialog_webview.setMessage("Please wait ...");
                progressDialog_webview.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                if (progressDialog_webview != null) {
                    progressDialog_webview.dismiss();
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: please give me upvote if my solution is relay helpful for you.